# prevent default working in Firefox but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

For the click of this link

```
<a id="c2c" href="#" class='test' style="margin-left:300px;"><img src="img.png" height="400" width="480" alt="Click Here"></a>
```

I have written this code

```
$('#c2c').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();                     
        window.location.href = "http://google.com"; 
     $.get("test.php?testnum=121212121",function(data){
        if(data == "no") window.location.href = "failure.html";
        else {
               window.location.href = "http://www.abc.com/get_data.php?data="+data;
                     }              
});
```

On this click of link, I am 
**1** - prventing default behaviour
**2** - setting href location
**3** - sending a get request with some params to another page
They all are working fine in FireFox but when I use try this code in Chrome/opera , it is not `3- sending the get request` and in error console I can see that Browser shows that 'Request Aborted'.
Any help?
**NOTE:** As far as I investigate it is due to not working of `event.preventDefault();` ,If I am right then How can I make this working OR what what would be the solution?

Comment: You change current page then you do a get request? Well I suppose Chrome just abort your request because you're (trying to) changing page (so pending requests are useless).

Comment: Ya, why this: `window.location.href = "tel:1111111"; `

Comment: but it shouldn't abort as I am using `preventDefault` So there must be a way

Comment: That's not what `preventDefault` does. In this instance it is stopping the window going to `#`

Comment: No, you prevent default behaviour of anchor click, not anything to do with the fact you are changing window location

Comment: It's changing page because you're assigning a new location to `window.location.href`. I don't know how it'll handle a `tel:` URL but in any case I don't think it's what you're trying to do...

Comment: OK fine as my knowledge us limited in front of you guys but It is working fine in FIREFOX , so why it is not working in Chrome

Comment: FIREFOX handle it differently, letting ajax request to complete, same behaviour as in onbeforeunload event. If you want a cross browser solution, just don't do that

Comment: @A.Wolff leave `tel:1111111` i have edited it to the `google.com` or it might be any URL.

Comment: But why do you want to change window location before sending a request? i don't get it?!

Comment: because this URL gives input and the GET request confirms the input from that redirecting URLthis is the whole flow that I have.You can say it requirement and this is the only solution.Is there any way?

Comment: As i understand it, you should then request this specific URL using ajax too

Comment: @A.Wolff ok this thing seems helpful

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove the location.href:

```
('#c2c').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();                     
  // window.location.href = "http://google.com"; remove this line or move it somewhere in the response callback of your ajax request
  $.get("test.php?testnum=121212121",function(data){
    if(data == "no") {
      window.location.href = "failure.html";
    } else {
      window.location.href = "http://www.abc.com/get_data.php?data="+data;
    }              
});
```

Chrome aborts the ajax request because window.location.href = "http://google.com"; makes the browser load google.com.
i can't give you a full code sample because i'm not sure what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score -4):

Change the anchor href

```
href="#"
```

to

```
href="javascript:void(0);"
```

Comment: Isn't `#` a perfect valid `href`? I don't really think this is his problem.

Comment: Agreed, this will make no functional difference as he is explicitly calling `preventDefault`

Comment: This won’t make a huge difference. The `javascript:` pseudo-protocol is horrible, by the way.